# Can I be sued for posting a night picture of the Eiffel Tower under CC-BY-SA?

Tags: united-states, france

I am an American tourist visiting France, and take a picture of the Eiffel Tower at night, the tower being the main and central subject of the picture.

Going back to the US, I upload this picture to my website under a CC-BY-SA license.

Can I be sued for infringing the copyright of the Eiffel Tower's lighting design?

Comment: Why the lighting design in particular? Why are you not worried about infringing the architecture or engineering?

Comment: @DaleM: The tower itself has come to the public domain long ago, fortunately. Only the lighting is recent.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. Your work is a derivative from the Eiffel lightning so you *could* be sued (the Société d’Exploitation de la Tour Eiffel may not be too interested in prosecuting you at a foreign country, and thus you might get away with it, but they certainly can).

You can license your copyright in the photo, but their copyright still remain, so the full photo cannot be used as CC-BY-SA unless they also licensed their piece or until it expires.

Depending of the contents of the photo you could claim that it is *Fair Use* (applicable to using the photo on your website, not to your claim that the photo is CC-BY-SA) or *de minimis* (if the eiffel tower was not the main focus, you should take into account the how it is interpretated in US and France).

You seem to think that by publishing from US you don't need to care about French copyright but that's not the case, since both are signers of the Berne Convention.

However, a possible outcome of being sued in the US *and winning* might be that court ruled that the Eiffel lightining is not really copyrightable.

Comment: He is publishing the material in the USA, not in France; therefore the Berne convention applies US copyright law, not French copyright law. I think? http://zvon.org/law/r/bern.html#p~6 Article 5 (4) a.

Comment: @Calchas, probably. A funny situation would be the US courts deciding that the Eiffel lightning isn't copyrightable, whereas French courts upheld that the lightning was [(link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20091116234240/http://www.lexeek.com/jus-luminum/decision-cass-03-03-1992,523975.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If it is subject to US law (and my understanding of the Berne convention Article 5(4)a is that it is) then **no**.

As detailed here http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/copyright-architectural-photos.html; architectural copyright came into force on 1 December 1990 and any buildings constructed before then (e.g. the Eifel Tower) are not protected.

I do not know when the current lighting installation was made but I think you would be safe even if this happened latter because:

1. It is debatable if the illumination of a piece of architecture is itself covered by copyright. The plans that document the design of the lighting clearly are as is the tower itself but I don't think that the term "architecture" can be extended to cover just the illumination; but I may be wrong about that.
2. Except for buildings that can’t be viewed from a public space, the copyright owner of a post-1990 building (the architect, developer or building owner) can’t prevent the making, distributing, or public display of pictures, paintings, photographs, or other pictorial representations of the building. (17 U.S.C. 120).

Comment: The lighting is from well after 1991.